# accumulator using 74hc194

Tags: register

I need help, I want make circuit that will load or store data from accumulator to another register. I have attached circuit I am not sure that diagram will work? [image]

Answer (score 1):

To copy data from the accumulator to the register, you just apply a positive clock edge to the register.

To copy data from the register to the accumulator, you just apply a positive clock edge to the accumulator.

You only want to clock the device receiving the data.

Comment: there are other signal SR,SL S0,S1 and MR ,SR and SL are not use in accumulator so how to connect S0,S1 and MR. I don't understand how to connect these signal between two registers

Comment: the 74194 datasheet will explain what the other signals do. Just connect them so that the IC does what you want - clock D onto Q when a clock edge occurs.